# How to get Java3D to work in IntelliJ on OS X

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, java-3d

I am a computer science student and I need to get Java3D working on my mac so that I can do the mandatory assignments.

I use IntelliJ as my IDE and it works great for Java and Python. But I am struggling to make it work for Java3D.

I've tried using my google-fu but to no avail. So I am coming here for some guidance. I have tried multiple tutorials/guides, here is what I have tried:

The code I am trying to run is from http://www.java3d.org/starting.html

```
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;

import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.ColorCube;

import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;

public class Hello3d {

    public Hello3d(){

    SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse();

    BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();

    group.addChild(new ColorCube(0.3));

    universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();

    universe.addBranchGraph(group);

    }

public static void main( String[] args ) {

    new Hello3d();

    }

}
```

First thing I tried was installing the Java3d Jar's and adding them to the dependencies: (I got them from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#java3d-1.5.1-oth-JPR

But I got the error:

```
Exception in thread "J3D-Renderer-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: apple/awt/ComponentModel
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.JAWT_DrawingSurface.GetDrawingSurfaceInfo0(Native Method)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.JAWT_DrawingSurface.GetDrawingSurfaceInfo(JAWT_DrawingSurface.java:56)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.macosx.MacOSXOnscreenGLDrawable$1.run(MacOSXOnscreenGLDrawable.java:165)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at  com.sun.opengl.impl.macosx.MacOSXOnscreenGLDrawable.lockSurface(MacOSXOnscreenGLDrawable.java:163)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.macosx.MacOSXOnscreenGLContext.makeCurrentImpl(MacOSXOnscreenGLContext.java:57)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.GLContextImpl.makeCurrent(GLContextImpl.java:134)
    at javax.media.j3d.JoglPipeline$QueryCanvas.doQuery(JoglPipeline.java:9049)
    at javax.media.j3d.JoglPipeline.getBestConfiguration(JoglPipeline.java:8797)
    at javax.media.j3d.Renderer.doWork(Renderer.java:514)
    at javax.media.j3d.J3dThread.run(J3dThread.java:275)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: apple.awt.ComponentModel
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 11 more
```

Then I learned that java3d is already installed on mac and I did the same. I added the jars to my dependencies. But I got the same error.

My last attempt was to follow this guide: http://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/

I downloaded the jars, put them all in the same folder and added them to my dependencies. But, again, I got the same error.

Now, it might be all my fault (I am not sure if I have to add them to my dependencies then add new Jars, but it always worked when I added different kind of API's) or it might be something more complex. Hopefully some of you guys have encountered the same issues and can help me.

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit: After trying what gouessej said, I got this error:

```
JavaVM WARNING: JAWT_GetAWT must be called after loading a JVM 
AWT not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: apple/awt/CGraphicsDevice
    at javax.media.j3d.GraphicsConfigTemplate3D.<clinit>(GraphicsConfigTemplate3D.java:55)
    at com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration(SimpleUniverse.java:368)
    at com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.Viewer.<init>(Viewer.java:348)
    at com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.Viewer.<init>(Viewer.java:298)
    at com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse.<init>(SimpleUniverse.java:215)
    at com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse.<init>(SimpleUniverse.java:177)
    at com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse.<init>(SimpleUniverse.java:88)
    at MAIN.<init>(MAIN.java:22)
    at MAIN.main(MAIN.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: apple.awt.CGraphicsDevice
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Can't you just use JavaFX which has 3D support? It comes as part of the standard library starting with Java 8.

Comment: @icza I've been trying to understand it, but it looks really complicated. But then again, I only gave it a quick glance. I might give it another shot. But if I can get java3d to work I would prefer it. My teacher uses it and my friends will probably use it as well. So if I struggle with something I can get help from them instead of googling and hoping someone has had the same problem as me (Relevant XKCD - "Wisdom of the Ancients" :P)

Comment: @icza Your answer is off topic. I'm fed up with people promoting their APIs instead of giving some help. JavaFX 3D API has some advantages and some drawbacks, it has higher minimal requirements, higher memory footprint, its performance isn't consistent across platforms and it has a lot less features than most scenegraph APIs written in Java. Actually, if you really want to use a more powerful scenegraph API, rather use JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation or JMonkeyEngine.

Comment: @gouessej No need to get upset. First, I didn't post any answers, I just commented. A comment can be "anything". Second, the standard library is not my API. I have no connection to Oracle whatsoever. I suggested something which might solve the questioner's original problem which was that he wasn't able to fire up a 3D library which if he had used JavaFX wouldn't exist in the first place because it's part of JRE8. Since other info (such as what he wanted to use the 3D library for) was not posted so it wasn't clear why he wanted exactly that library, so I suggested a trouble free alternative.

Comment: There is no "trouble free" alternative even though using a standard Java API which is part of J2SE is initially easier than using a 3rd party library because there is nothing to install. IMHO, the questioner asks for help on installing Java 3D, he doesn't ask which 3D library to use, that's why I consider your comment is off topic. People on SO should refrain themselves from advising the use of other libraries except when there is no solution with the library. If you had a problem with your car, suggesting you to buy another one from another automaker instead of fixing it wouldn't be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't followed my instructions, the answer is in [the "troubleshooting" section](http://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/#troubleshooting). You have to uninstall the obsolete version of Java3D **before** installing a new version. If you don't do it, the JVM will always load in priority the one dirtily copied into it or the one installed as an extension, which is often the case under OS X.

When it is done, install JogAmp and Java3D, just follow the instructions, it's very straightforward. Moreover (as stated in the tutorial), you should rather ask the questions about Java3D on our [official forum](http://forum.jogamp.org/java3d-f3728156.html). The JogAmp contributors can't register everywhere, on Reddit, here, ...

IntelliJ probably allows to put some JARs into the classpath, it shouldn't be difficult.

**Warning**: Switching back to Java for OS X (Apple JVM 1.6) is a bad solution because its JRE will still pick the obsolete version of Java3D (1.5) if you don't uninstall it, **[Apple Java is deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Java/JavaSnowLeopardUpdate3LeopardUpdate8RN/NewandNoteworthy/NewandNoteworthy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010380-CH4-SW1)**, you won't benefit of the bug fix included in Java3D 1.6 and your application won't work when Apple Java is no longer supported at all by your operating system, for example after an upgrade. The only version of Java3D compatible with OpenJDK and Oracle Java 1.8 under OS X is Java3D 1.6.0.

Comment: I tried it, but this time I got another error. I've edited the main post and added the error.

Comment: Sorry but the other error is similar and has the same root cause. Either there is still an old version of Java3D installed by default on your machine somewhere, or you use (by mistake) the Oracle JARs because Java3D 1.6.0 (the latest version) doesn't use classes in apple/awt whereas Java3D 1.5 does. As long as you will get this kind of error, you will have to look for an obsolete version of Java3D on your machine as I explained here: http://forum.jogamp.org/Getting-Java3d-to-work-on-OS-X-on-IntelliJ-tp4033405p4033406.html

Comment: I advise you to delete all JARs even those you downloaded, to look for Java3D on your machine and to delete all Java3D JARs you will find elsewhere in order to avoid any confusion and to start working on a clean machine. Then, follow my instructions and it will work. If you still get the same error, it means that there is still an obsolete version of Java3D on your machine.

Comment: I updated my tutorial in order to clarify how to uninstall the obsolete versions of Java 3D but don't put the JARs into the same directory, this is exactly what is discouraged to do in my tutorial, there is a reason for that.

Comment: There won't be any confusion with JOGL 1 under Mac in the next pre build of Java 3D (1.6.0 pre 12) as it will use JOGL 2.3.1 which uses different package names :) Enjoy: https://github.com/hharrison/java3d-core/pull/16